# Unexpected behaviour for time comparisons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model

OK so i have a record that was created 26 days ago but when i do a comparison to 2.days.ago it tells me false i don't know why, i've been at this for like 3 hours trying several things and doing a lot of googling but nothing seems to work
Here's a sample of my terminal code

> `2.1.1 :066 > Ticket4Midnite.first.created_at
>     Ticket4Midnite Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ticket4_midnites".* FROM "ticket4_midnites" LIMIT 1
>    => Fri, 04 Jul 2014 19:10:00 UTC +00:00
>   2.1.1 :067 > helper.time_ago_in_words(Ticket4Midnite.first.created_at)
>     Ticket4Midnite Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ticket4_midnites".* FROM "ticket4_midnites" LIMIT 1
>    => "26 days"
>   2.1.1 :068 > Ticket4Midnite.first.created_at>=2.days.ago
>     Ticket4Midnite Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ticket4_midnites".* FROM "ticket4_midnites" LIMIT 1
>    => false
>   2.1.1 :069 >`

And a Sample of my table datatypes i'm using a postgresql database

> `Table "public.ticket4_midnites"
>             Column           |            Type             |                           Modifiers
>   ---------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
>    id                        | integer                     | not null default nextval('ticket4_midnites_id_seq'::regclass)
>    company                   | character varying(255)      |
>    surfaceLocation           | character varying(255)      |
>    DownholeLocation          | character varying(255)      |
>    Field                     | character varying(255)      |
>    SiteSupervisor            | character varying(255)      |
>    SafeWorkPermit            | character varying(255)      |
>    Date                      | character varying(255)      |
>    DayNightTour              | character varying(255)      |
>    RigNumber                 | character varying(255)      |
>    ReportNumber              | character varying(255)      |
>    returnToBase              | boolean                     |
>    StayinCamp                | boolean                     |
>    prejobsafety              | boolean                     |
>    rigWalkAroundDone         | boolean                     |
>    AirKillSafetyCheck        | boolean                     |
>    FunctionTestBOP           | boolean                     |
>    DrillHeadwhileTappingRods | boolean                     |
>    BOPDrillSatisfactory      | boolean                     |
>    created_at                | timestamp without time zone | not null
>    updated_at                | timestamp without time zone | not null
>    username                  | character varying(255)      |
>    status                    | character varying(255)      |
>   Indexes:
>       "ticket4_midnites_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)`

If there's any other information you need, i'll provide any help would be appreciated thanks!!

Comment: Please format code as code, not a quote.

Comment: Your code is asking if the record was created at more recently than 2 days ago, which is false - as you said the record was created 26 days ago

Answer (score 1):

Like Frederick Cheung pointed out in the comments, you are misunderstanding what `Ticket4Midnite.first.created_at>=2.days.ago` does.

By breaking apart the code you can see what it actually is doing.
Look at it like this:

```
(Ticket4Midnite.first.created_at) >= (2.days.ago)
```

This is just comparing timestamps.

```
(July 4th @ Some time) >= (July 28th @ current time)
```

Which is asking if that first time stamp is a time **sooner** than two days ago.

Since it isn't, it returns `false`.

As another example, from the [ruby-docs for Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html):

```
t1 = Time.new(2010)
t2 = Time.new(2011)

t1 == t2 #=> false
t1 == t1 #=> true
t1 <  t2 #=> true
t1 >  t2 #=> false
```

Greater than and less than for time comparisons are asking which time came first.

So for your case, just flip the direction of your comparison and it will behave as you expect.

Comment: So that means i want <= then right ? i feel so stupid right now lol

Comment: Exactly (also added that to my answer). And it's an honest mistake. If you think about how long that time is before now and compare that way it would make sense.